# Twig For Loop Fails to Iterate Over Nested Schema Properties

Tags: twig, schema

I'm new to twig, and I'm trying to create a nav menu with sub menus from a provided schema which looks like this-

```
  menu_items: [
        {
          url: 'http://testurl.com',
          text: 'Menu Item 1',
          active: true,
          sub_menu: [
            {
              url: 'http://testurl.com',
              text: 'Sub menu Item 1',
            },
            {
              url: 'http://testurl.com',
              text: 'Sub menu Item 2',
            },
          ],
        },
      ]
```

The menu is showing up just fine, but I'm struggling to get the correct syntax to get those sub menu items populated. I put an if statement in because there's not always a sub menu, and then a for loop to create a list item for each sub menu item in the schema, but alas.

```
  {% if menu_items %}
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {% for item in menu_items %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
            {% if item.sub_menu %}
              <ul>
                {% for sub_menu in item %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="{{ item.sub_menu.url }}">
                     {{ item.sub_menu.text }}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                 {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  {% endif %}
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not referencing the `sub_menu` items correctly. Try

```
{% for sub in item.sub_menu %} ... {% endfor %}
```

It's also helpful if the `sub_menu` array is empty. The empty test evaluates to true if the variable is null, false, an empty array, or an empty string

```
{% if item.sub_menu is not empty %} ... {% endif %}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much. I just couldn't get the syntax quite right.